# Install zsh without root access?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, zsh

Is it possible (and how)? I really need this for several remote computers where I've got ssh access (but no root access).

Comment: Why is this closed?! This is very helpful Q&A for community.

Comment: hi, sorry. this isnt very programming specific and it is very broad. Maybe a Q&A community less coding oriented can help

Comment: Precompiled binaries here: https://github.com/romkatv/zsh-bin/releases

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try the `chsh` command. Are you sure zsh isn't installed on the distant computer? If not, you can do this (quoted from [zsh FAQ Section 1.7](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq01.html))

The basic idea is to use exec  to replace the current shell with zsh. Often you can do this in a login file such as .profile (if your shell is sh or ksh) or .login (if it's csh). Make sure you have some way of altering the file (e.g. via FTP) before you try this as exec is often rather unforgiving.

If you have zsh in a subdirectory bin of your home directory, put this in .profile:

```
[ -f $HOME/bin/zsh ] && exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l
```

or if your login shell is csh or tcsh, put this in .login:

```
if ( -f ~/bin/zsh ) exec ~/bin/zsh -l
```

(in each case the -l tells zsh it is a login shell).

If you want to check this works before committing yourself to it, you can make the login shell ask whether to exec zsh. The following work for Bourne-like shells:

```
[ -f $HOME/bin/zsh ] && {
        echo "Type Y to run zsh: \c"
        read line
        [ "$line" = Y ] && exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l
}
```

and for C-shell-like shells:

```
if ( -f ~/bin/zsh ) then
        echo -n "Type Y to run zsh: "
        if ( "$<" == Y ) exec ~/bin/zsh -l
endif
```

It's not a good idea to put this (even without the -l) into .cshrc, at least without some tests on what the csh is supposed to be doing, as that will cause *every* instance of csh to turn into a zsh and will cause csh scripts (yes, unfortunately some people write these) which do not call `csh -f` to fail. If you want to tell xterm to run zsh, change the SHELL environment variable to the full path of zsh at the same time as you exec zsh (in fact, this is sensible for consistency even if you aren't using xterm). If you have to exec zsh from your .cshrc, a minimum safety check is if ($?prompt) exec zsh.

If you like your login shell to appear in the process list as -zsh, you can link zsh to -zsh (e.g. by ln -s ~/bin/zsh ~/bin/-zsh) and change the exec to exec -zsh. (Make sure -zsh is in your path.) This has the same effect as the -l option.

Footnote: if you DO have root access, make sure zsh goes in /etc/shells on all appropriate machines, including NIS clients, or you may have problems with FTP to that machine.

Comment: Skip permissions errors by swapping `-f` for `-x`: you want to make sure `~/bin/zsh` is not just a file (`-f`), but that it’s an _executable_ file (`-x`).

Answer (score 78):

Download zsh with:

```
wget -O zsh.tar.xz https://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/latest/download
mkdir zsh && unxz zsh.tar.xz && tar -xvf zsh.tar -C zsh --strip-components 1
cd zsh
```

You can compile zsh yourself, for example:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

and then start it explicitly, or programmatically from your current shell's startup file (put `exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l` in the right spot).

Comment: On version 5.2 the prefix should be just `--prefix=$HOME`, otherwise it will end in `$HOME/bin/bin`

Comment: @ilija139 Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Just noticed that then the `lib` folder is also placed in `$HOME` :/
Maybe best is to install to some other folder and symlink it to `$HOME/bin`

Comment: The latest zsh release tarball is in `tar.xz` format. The above command does not work any more.

Comment: To make this compatible with the latest zsh tarball which is in the xz format, use:

`wget -O zsh.tar.xz https://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/latest/download`

`mkdir zsh && unxz zsh.tar.xz && tar -xvzf zsh.tar -C zsh --strip-components 1`

`cd zsh`

Comment: @shreyasgm Thank you for your valuable contribution. I have updated the commands accordingly.

Comment: I nominated this Q&A for re-opening. Very helpful answer.

Comment: @shreyasgm I get this error...
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

EDIT: `tar xvzf` should be `tar xvf`

Comment: @GodstimeOsarobo The zsh distribution file has changed from gzip format to xz format. You need to use unxz, not gunzip.

Comment: @Jens well, tar xvf is what did the job for me ‍♂️

Comment: I tried a couple of methods, finally only conda install -c conda-forge zsh worked for me. With this, the installation of oh-my-zsh also works

Answer (score 2):

If the machine has zsh on it you should be fine to just execute `zsh` on a prompt to swap, if that works you can either try `chsh` to swap your shell (should work without root) or when you're connecting with `ssh` put `ssh -t hostname zsh` to start it automatically.

Answer (score -4):

Create a directory in your user account directory, unpack [zsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/) and after that use `./config`, `make` and `make install`.

Comment: The question was about installing *without* root access.