# ZSH environment on remote computer broken, crashes as soon as logging in via ssh

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh

I had trouble running oh-my-zsh on a remote computer, to which I don't have root access, so I tried   [downloading and compiling zsh by following these steps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293565/11542903)

I know I messed up on the last step, where I was supposed to start zsh ["explicitly, or programmatically from your current shell's startup file (put `exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l` in the right spot)."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293565/11542903)

I added `exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l` in the first line of my ~/.zshrc and sourced it, and everything froze.
Now after logging out I can't remove my changes because the shell crashes as soon as I log in to the remote via ssh:

```
Last login: Thu Aug 20 11:50:42 2020 from ***.***.***.*


~/.zshrc:3: exec format error: ~/bin/zsh
Connection to *my.remote* closed.
```

alternatively, VScode remote ssh shoots back this error after the terminal crashes:

```
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l'" terminated with exit code: 126.
```

Any help for my stupid mistake is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ssh -t host vim ~/.zshrc to edit it back. you created a dead loop

Comment: Thanks @arslan2012! I was able to delete the line. However I'm still confused as to where I should have put the line. Do I have to manually `exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l` every time?

Comment: first of all why your zsh is in your home? that's a bad practice.
second, you should put your zsh path in /etc/shells file and then use chsh to change your default shell

Comment: @arslan2012 There are very good reasons for installing the shell in their home directory, the primary one being they don't have write access to any of the standard directories.

Comment: thanks @chepner and yes, this was my problem/intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `exec $HOME/bin/zsh -l` in the appropriate configuration file for your login shell. Assuming that is `bash`, add the line to `.bash_profile`. As recommended in a comment, use

```
ssh -t host vim
```

to start `vim` (or the editor of your choice) to edit `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` appropriately.